# How to populate a List of Class of string?

Tags: c#, list

A dumb C# question, if I have this code:

```
public class singleString
{
        public string ss { get; set; }
}
List<singleString> manyString = new List<singleString>();
```

How can I populate `manyString` to something like `{"1", "2", "3"}` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
List<singleString> manyString = new List<singleString>()
{
    new singleString(){ss="1"},
    new singleString(){ss="2"},
    new singleString(){ss="3"},
};
```

Comment: The parenthesis are not required.

Comment: Yes, they can be removed but if you put them there will be no error.

Answer (score 5):

Define implicit conversion operator

```
public class singleString {
    public string ss { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator singleString(string s) {
        return new singleString { ss = s };
    }
}
```

Then, use List initializer

```
var manyString = new List<singleString>() { "1", "2", "3" };
```

You can also initialize an array using the same operator

```
singleString[] manyString = { "1", "2", "3" };
```

Comment: any advantage of using implicit converter? Out of the two, which one you prefer and why? thanks.

Comment: @Jeb50 you asked `How can I populate manyString to something like {"1", "2", "3"} ?`. I would've preferred `List<string>`

Comment: don't get what you meant by _Iwould've preferred_ `List<string>`. Since you provided two ways to populate the List, curious which one you prefer.

Comment: @Jeb50 Unless you have a good reason to create `manyString` class, just use the `string` type directly.

Comment: agree, it's a bit silly. Reason is would like to have a dynamic size of string[].